# ¿Cómo esperar la finalización de eventos asíncronos sin consultar cada cierto tiempo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asincronismo

### Contexto

Para un sistema, existe un proceso que sincroniza información desde una API externa (6 tablas en total) usando transacciones con Web SQL, este proceso se hace de forma manual mediante el botón `SINCRONIZAR` y mientras el proceso se está ejecutando es necesario evitar que inicien sesión o que vuelvan a sincronizar por lo que ambos botones se bloquean:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Proceso actual

Traté de comentar las partes irrelevantes para que sea un poco más fácil de entender.

Mediante el uso de [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) y [clearInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval) conseguí, de alguna manera, que se pueda esperar la finalización de varios eventos asíncronos:

```
// URLs para consumir cada tabla del API externo
// baseAPI viene desde otro archivo
var cultivosAPI = baseAPI + "/api/cultivos/";
var usuariosAPI = baseAPI + "/api/usuarios/";
var terminalesAPI = baseAPI + "/api/terminales/";
var personalAPI = baseAPI + "/api/personal/";
var laboresAPI = baseAPI + "/api/labores/";
var plantasAPI = baseAPI + "/api/plantas/";
// Objeto para saber el estado de la sincronización de cada
// tabla
var updateStates = {};
// ID inicial del intervalo usado en la función setInterval()
var intervalId = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){
    // ...
    // Boton ACTUALIZAR, antes de sincronizar se asegura
    // de que exista conexión con el servidor
    $("#updateBtn").on("click", testConnection);
    // ...
});

function testConnection() {
    $.ajax(
        baseAPI
    ).done(function (data) {
        // Si todo está bien, sincronizar las tablas
        updateTables();
    }).fail(function() {
        // ...
    });
}

function updateTables() {
    // ...
    // Hash para conocer el resultado de actualización de cada tabla,
    // es la variable definidida arriba
    updateStates = {
        "cultivo": null,
        "labor": null,
        "personal": null,
        "planta": null,
        "terminal": null,
        "usuario": null
    };
    // Deshabilitar botones
    $("#loginBtn").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#updateBtn").prop("disabled", true);
    // ...
    // ***************************************************
    // Esta es la parte asíncrona en donde se llama el API
    // de cada tabla
    // ***************************************************
    // Insertar cultivos
    $.getJSON(cultivosAPI, {
        format: "json"
    }).done(function (data) {
        db.transaction(function(tx) {
            // SQL y otras cosas
        });
    }).fail(function(data) {
        // Marcamos la tabla como incompleta
        updateStates["cultivo"] = false;
        // ...
    });
    // Insertar personal
    $.getJSON(personalAPI, {
        format: "json"
    }).done(function (data) {
        db.transaction(function(tx) {
            // SQL y otras cosas
        });
    }).fail(function(data) {
        // Marcamos la tabla como incompleta
        updateStates["personal"] = false;
        // ...
    });
    // Insertar terminales
    $.getJSON(terminalesAPI, {
        format: "json"
    }).done(function (data) {
        db.transaction(function(tx) {
            // SQL y otras cosas
        });
    }).fail(function(data) {
        // Marcamos la tabla como incompleta
        updateStates["terminal"] = false;
        // ...
    });
    // Insertar usuarios
    $.getJSON(usuariosAPI, {
        format: "json"
    }).done(function (data) {
        db.transaction(function(tx) {
            // SQL y otras cosas
        });
    }).fail(function(data) {
        // Marcamos la tabla como incompleta
        updateStates["usuario"] = false;
        // ...
    });
    // Insertar labores
    $.getJSON(laboresAPI, {
        format: "json"
    }).done(function (data) {
        db.transaction(function(tx) {
            // SQL y otras cosas
        });
    }).fail(function(data) {
        // Marcamos la tabla como incompleta
        updateStates["labor"] = false;
        // ...
    });
    // Insertar plantas
    $.getJSON(plantasAPI, {
        format: "json"
    }).done(function (data) {
        db.transaction(function(tx) {
            // SQL y otras cosas
        });
    }).fail(function(data) {
        // Marcamos la tabla como incompleta
        updateStates["planta"] = false;
        // ...
    });
    // Esperar que finalicen las actualizaciones para habilitar
    // los botones, valida cada segundo
    intervalId = setInterval(updateIsFinished, 1000);
}

function updateIsFinished() {
    // El proceso puede haber terminado sin terminar de actualizar por algún
    // error encontrado
    var updated = true;
    var finished = true;
    // Iteramos cada estado de la tabla, si la tabla tiene un valor
    // false es porque hubo un error en la llamada AJAX, si tiene un
    // valor null es porque el AJAX aun no finaliza 
    for (table in updateStates) {
        if (updateStates[table] == false) {
            updated = false;
        }
        if (updateStates[table] == null) {
            finished = false;
        }
    }
    if (updated || finished) {
        // Limpiar el intervalo
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        // Resetear valores globales
        updateStates = {};
        intervalId = 0;
        // Habilitar botones
        if (updated) {
            $("#loginBtn").prop("disabled", false);
            $("#updateBtn").prop("disabled", false);
        } else if (finished) {
            $("#updateBtn").prop("disabled", false);
        }
    }
}
```

### Pregunta

Aunque funciona, siento que podría existir una forma más adecuada para conseguirlo sin la necesidad de estar verificando cada segundo. Intenté usando [jQuery.when()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) pero no funcionó.

¿Cómo puedo esperar eventos asíncronos sin necesidad de estar verificando cada cierto intervalo de tiempo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Si estás usando jQuery, tu mejor opción es `$.when`.

La función `when` recibe una lista de objetos *Promise* y devuelve a su vez otro *Promise* que será resuelto cuando cada uno de los items sean resueltos.  Al ser un *Promise* puedes encadenar los métodos `done` y `fail` como harías normalmente.

Un ejemplo:

```
var req1 = $.getJSON('url/1').done(function() { ... });
var req2 = $.getJSON('url/2').done(function() { ... });

$.when(req1, req2)
 .done(function() { ... });
 .fail(function() { ... });
```

En ese caso `done` se ejecuta si **todos** los *requests* tuvieron éxito y `fail` si **al menos uno** falló.

Para tu problema específico, y luego de una pequeña refactorización :), yo intentaría resolverlo de una manera parecida a esta:

```
function updateTables() {
    $("#loginBtn").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#updateBtn").prop("disabled", true);

    var endpoints = [{
            name: 'cultivo',
            url: 'api/cultivo',
            updated: null 
        }, {
            name: 'labor',
            url: 'api/labor',
            updated: null 
        }
        // ...
    ]

    var promises = endpoints.map(function(item) {
        $.getJSON(baseAPI + item.url, { format: 'json' }, function(data) {
            db.transaction(function(tx) { 
                // ...
            })
        })
        .done(function() { 
            item.updated = true;
        })
        .fail(function() {
            item.updated = false;
        });
    });

    $.when.apply($, promises)
        .done(function() {
            $("#loginBtn").prop("disabled", false);
            $("#updateBtn").prop("disabled", false);
        })
        .fail(function() {
            $("#updateBtn").prop("disabled", false);
        });
}
```

Si el código de cada *endpoint* es diferente en cada caso, entonces podrías colocarlo en el *array* de *endpoints*:

```
{
    name: 'cultivo',
    url: 'api/cultivo',
    updated: null,
    done: function(data) {
       db.transaction(function(tx) { 
            // código específico para "cultivo"
        })
    }
}
```

y luego

```
$.getJSON(baseAPI + item.url, { format: 'json' }, item.done);
```

Comment: Interesante el tema de los Promises, lo pruebo en un rato. Creo que no usé correctamente la función `jQuery.when()`

Answer (score 4):

Una de las soluciones que me vienen a la mente es usar el [Ajaxstart](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) y [Ajaxstop](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) de jQuery, que permiten saber cuando se esta ejecutando la petición y cuando esta finalizo. Para tu código seria algo como esto:

```
//Bloqueo los botones
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
   $("#loginBtn").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#updateBtn").prop("disabled", true);
});

//Bloqueo los botones
$(document).ajaxStop(function(){
   $("#loginBtn").prop("disabled", false);
    $("#updateBtn").prop("disabled", false);
});
```

Ya con esto, se sabrá cuando están listas las peticiones y liberan los botones para el login. De mi parte la he usado solo para hacer 1 petición, no múltiples, pero creo que igual puede funcionar, o lo mas que debes modificar es hacer las peticiones anidas.

Comment: Buenas referencias, las tengo que probar.